# Error: Insufficient credentials provided in constructor argument in AssistantV1.BaseService.initCredentials

Tags: ibm-watson

I am Building a virtual assistant that responds to a trigger words
using [this](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/add-a-trigger-word-to-your-watson-assistant/) document.

I followed the tutorial and when I ran the `npm start` i got this error.

```
C:\wat\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\base_service.js:307
            throw new Error(errorMessage);
            ^

Error: Insufficient credentials provided in constructor argument. Refer to the documentation for the required parameters. Common examples are username/password and iam_apikey.
at AssistantV1.BaseService.initCredentials (C:\wat\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\base_service.js:307:23)
at AssistantV1.BaseService (C:\wat\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\base_service.js:113:29)
at new AssistantV1 (C:\wat\node_modules\ibm-watson\assistant\v1.js:66:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wat\run.js:24:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chatbot-with-voice-activation-wake-word@1.0.0 start: `node ./run.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chatbot-with-voice-activation-wake-word@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\diana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-    16T13_56_28_690Z-debug.log
```

I have created three files as in the document:

- `.env` file which has the credential info
- `package.json` and
- `run.js` file.

I can't figure it out that it couldn't access the `read-credentials-file` which is stored as `.ts` file.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the file ".env" that you created, and make sure that you updated the credentials according to your service credentials.